# jQuery make a series of div tags into an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of div tags as follows:

```
<div>
    <div class="MB_SLOT" id="slot1"></div>
    <div class="MB_SLOT" id="slot2"></div>
    <div class="MB_SLOT" id="slot3"></div>
    <div class="MB_SLOT" id="slot4"></div>
</div>
```

I want to put the `MB_SLOT` elements into an unordered list (`ul`) but everything (including the containing div) has been generated by an API that I have no control over and the number of generated elements can vary from page to page.

If I use `j$( ".MB_SLOT" ).wrap( "<li></li>" );` I can wrap each of the `MB_SLOT` elements but I don't know how to then wrap that in `<ul></ul>`

Can anyone advise on the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your li's a class for more specificity

```
$( ".MB_SLOT" ).wrap( "<li class='list-item'></li>" );
```

Then use .wrapAll() to wrap all instances of "list-item"

```
$( ".list-item" ).wrapAll( "<ul></ul>" );
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjrh7m1d/)

Comment: Nice use of `wrapAll()` - the name always implies (incorrectly) wrap *each* to me.  Updated fiddle with border on the `ul`: https://jsfiddle.net/yjrh7m1d/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is the parent always the same, a `<div>` element?

If so, you could use:

```
var parent = $( ".MB_SLOT:first").parents("div"), // find parent <div>
    ul = $("<ul></ul>"); // setup <ul> element

parent.prepend( ul ); // add <ul> element as first child in parent

$( ".MB_SLOT" ).appendTo( ul ); // move .MB_SLOT as children of <ul>
$( ".MB_SLOT" ).wrap( "<li></li>" ); // wrap .MB_SLOT in <li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/opzLLx9h/

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this (rebuild the `div`s into `li`s) https://jsfiddle.net/rwghggx4/2/

i could be mistaken, but the reason why this example "builds" an li instead of just wrapping the `div` in an `li` is because you're not supposed to put `div`s in `li`s.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function transformToUL() {
    var html = "<ul>";
    $('.MB_SLOT').each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
        html += "<li class='MB_SLOT' id='" + $(this).attr('id') + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
    });
    $('.container').append(html);    
    $('.changeToUL').hide();
  }

  transformToUL();
});
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `li`'s can contain [Flow Content (MDN Spec Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) which does include `div`